# Solr AnalyticsQuery API returns analytics by documents that don't match query

Tags: solr

Solr [AnalyticsQuery API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/AnalyticsQuery+API) returns analytics by documents that don't match query.

I have core named 'documents' in Solr. There are some fields like 'id', 'url', 'text', 'domain'.
Also I have ResourceAnalyticsCollector which counts how many documents belongs to each resource.
Example of result of resource analytics is:

> resources:{
>
> - example.com: 456
> - example2.com: 123
> - ...
>
> }

First time I found problem when the query was by one domain but analytics returned result with few domains.

Example:

Solr query: `domain:example.com`

Number of documents returned by this query: 1000(All this documents belongs to *example.com*)

Analytics result:

> resources:{
>
> - example.com: 700
> - example2.com: 100
> - example3.com: 100
> - example4.com: 100
>
> }

I looked for all documents by `/select` search handler and all of this documents was belonged to `example.com` domain.

But when I looked in analytics for documents, I have found that there are many documents which don't match query. But number of documents is the same.

Here is my analytics module:

```
public class ResourceAnalyticsCollector extends DelegatingCollector{
        
    public ResourceAnalyticsCollector(ResponseBuilder rb, IndexSearcher searcher) {
        this.rb = rb;
        this.searcher = searcher;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void collect(int docNum){
        Document doc;
        doc = searcher.doc(docNum);
    
             //Output document id for logs
        String docId = doc.get(AnalyticsConstants.ID_SOLR_FIELD);
        System.out.println("Doc id = " + docId);

        documentList.add(doc);
        delegate.collect(docNum);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void finish(){
        rb.rsp.add(TOTAL_RESULT_FIELD, this.getAnalyticsContext(documentList));
    }
```

I think this is the bug of the Solr. But if someone could help me with this problem, it would be great!

I have create mini version of my analytics, with core. Name of file "Analytics_API_problem.rar".
You can download it by these [link](http://1drv.ms/15NsYul)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use query like &fq={!myanalytic param1=a param2=b cost=101}

Comment: @MayankJain No it shouldn't - if it's a valid answer, it should be posted as an answer. You will see a lot of people posting simple answers as comments if they're unsure that that's actually the problem, or if they're just giving a hint in the right direction rather than actually giving the full answer, but there's nothing wrong with a single line answer when appropriate, and when there isn't any extra explanation possible to add.